# How to export data from excel file to script

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, export

I am using Python Selenium and i am trying to export data from an excel file to my script

It should import the USERNAME and PASSWORD ( look picture ) to the INPUT form with sending the keys

excel list name doesnt care

```
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//INPUT[@id='SignIn_email_uid']").send_keys(USERNAME)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//INPUT[@id='SignIn_password_password']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
```

[image: EXCEL-LIST]

Answer (score 0):

for excel handling, pandas(https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a good option. This will help with the data-driven framework and also for the execution report.